# URL links in itemize environment

Tags: itemize, urls, url

I am adding some url directions in an itemize environment, but the result is not the expected, and there are several issues with the text width. I don´t know how to fix it (if it is possible).

[image]

Here is the summary of the packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.9cm, right=2.9cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
```

And the code for the url list:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item A Timeline Of Atomic Models, página 5: \url{https://medium.com/@Intlink.edu/a-timeline-of-atomic-models-cb2607b1da85}. 
    \item Giphy.com, página 22: \url{https://giphy.com/gifs/W2KU5PKZJHnbF4pwc2}. 
    \item Falstad.com, página 24: \url{http://www.falstad.com/qmatom/}.
    \item Desmos, página 29: \url{https://www.desmos.com/?lang=es}.
    \item Geogebra, página 29: \url{https://www.geogebra.org/graphing?lang=es}. 
    \item FisQuiweb, página 29: \url{https://fisquiweb.es/}.
    \item Fisiquimicamente, página 29: \url{https://fisiquimicamente.com/}.
    \item Preguntas test, página 30: \url{https://forms.gle/4FT3xK3pNAECv3Uh9}.
    \item Canal de divulgación científica Veritasium, página 47: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xKZRpAsWL8}
    \item Este otro vídeo, página 47: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9Goyscbazk}.
    \item Clase de Química del MIT, página 47: \url{https://youtu.be/ustfXi-mpkI?t=1210} (repetido en la leyenda de la figura).
    \item Este vídeo de Physics Demo, página 49: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oae5fa-f0S0}.
    \item chem.libretexts.org, página 49: \url{https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Harper_College/CHM_110\%3A_Fundamentals_of_Chemistry/02\%3A_Radiation-_Pros_and_Cons/2.09\%3A_The_Bohr_Model_-_Atoms_with_Orbits#:~:text=In\%201913\%2C\%20the\%20Danish\%20physicist,electromagnetic\%20radiation\%20(or\%20light)}.
    \item \href{https://www.amazon.es/Timeline-Inventos-Juego-Cartasen-Espa\%C3\%B1ol/dp/B08H2JD8NY/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?adgrpid=57756896578&dchild=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhr2FBhDbARIsACjwLo12xDwKgq3Mfm7UIWMhowZ8tqM-UtA48Nn4WoXwMJU0yIWQToZrh-YaAgfDEALw_wcB&hvadid=275326979987&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1005546&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=7439549272998105436&hvtargid=kwd-310677345743&hydadcr=19744_1802671&keywords=timeline+juego&qid=1622121001&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFFRkYzWU9RNFpGNiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRJZD1BMDM5NDgyMTFOWFM2R1JHVVgxMzkmZW5jcnlwdGVkQWRJZD1BMDUwODkxNjM2RUhaSlhJSk9YSkQmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl}{``Timeline''}, página 50. Link es muy largo con caracteres que no detecta \LaTeX, buscar ``timeline'' en Amazon.
    \item Vídeo de The Science Asylum, página 51: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQJj2kBJ5A8}.
    \item Otro vídeo Science Asylum, página 51: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch
    ?v=EOHYT5q5lhQ}.
    \item  Vídeo Date un Voltio, página 51: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uswkXJipM9o}.
    \item Lista de reproducción Quantum Fracture, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v
    =OABUuXQcnJQ\&list=PLOPFAg4mOJ10rS1Sg9AWA6YA9A54v7XKK}.
    \item ``El misterio del aire'', página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OABUuXQcnJQ&list=PLOPFAg4mOJ10rS1Sg9AWA6YA9A54v7XKK}.
    \item Experimento de la doble rendija, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9ScxCemsPM&list=PLOPFAg4mOJ10rS1Sg9AWA6YA9A54v7XKK&index=3}.
    \item La dualidad onda-partícula, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBEq1rhRbC4&list=PLOPFAg4mOJ10rS1Sg9AWA6YA9A54v7XKK&index=4}.
    \item El principio de indeterminación de Heisenberg, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W8i-BVWehc&list=PLOPFAg4mOJ10rS1Sg9AWA6YA9A54v7XKK&index=7}.
    \item``Los átomos NO son así'', página 52:  \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxIxWTTsBj4&t=102s}.
    \item El vídeo es del canal Minute Physics, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2Xb2GFK2yc&list=LL&index=2}
    \item Es de otro canal que ya he mencionado, The Science Asylum, página 52: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPkcDWLBsrI}.
    \item Cuaderno de Cultura Científica,página 53: \url{https://culturacientifica.com/2019/04/29/la-ley-de-proporciones-definidas-y-la-unidad-de-masa-atomica/}.
    \item Tres modelos atómicos que quizá no conocías, página 53: \url{https://naukas.com/2013/04/10/tres-modelos-atomicos-que-quiza-no-conocias/}.
    \item ¿Cómo sabemos que los átomos existen?, página 53:  \url{https://naukas.com/2017/09/01/como-sabemos-que-existen-los-atomos/}.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Try \usepackage{xurl}, it will allow the url's to break in more places.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It worked perfectly!